# how to change attributes of function objects in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, attributes

In the code below, I define a function `f` which has variable y.
I tried to call f.y outside the function and it throws error.
but it allows me to assign `f.y=11` or even new attribute `f.x=12`. but calling f() does not update the `y`. so where does this `f.y` or `f.x` gets attached to. and is it possible or not to change the `y` inside the function.

```
>>> def f():
...   y = 10
...   print y
... 
>>> f.y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'y'
>>> f.y = 11
>>> f()
10
```

EDIT: This does not help either

```
    >>> def f():
...   f.y = 10
...   print f.y
... 
>>> f()
10
>>> f.y=11
>>> f()
10
>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better if you explained what you're trying to accomplish.  To first directly answer your question:

`f` refers to the `function` object that you created.  You can assign attributes to any object that has a `__dict__` attribute (i.e. what you were doing with `f.y=11`).  Go ahead and check out `dir(f)`, you'll see that it has a `__dict__`.  It is in essence a syntactic wrapper around a normal `dict` that you would normally access by doing something like

```
my_dict['y'] = 10
```

Note that this `dict` has *nothing* to do with any locals that you defined within your function.  Generally you don't want to be doing this at all, instead favoring an explicit `dict` when you need a `dict`.  The situation when you do want to use this syntax to access an object's `__dict__`: classes.  I cover that briefly below.

---

Now, since I think you're trying to reinvent the wheel here, I'll try to go over what you probably *should* be doing.  Since I don't know what you're trying to do, I'll use the shotgun approach and cover as many as I can think of.

-Make it as an argument to your function, or better, supply it as a *default parameter* to f, which you can optionally change.

```
def f(y=10):
    print y

f()
#prints 10

f(y=11)
#prints 11
```

-**Return** your value from `f`.  This of course gives you access to the variable.  Basic stuff, but..

```
def f(y=10):
    return y

f()
Out[9]: 10

f(y=11)
Out[10]: 11
```

-Make `f` a `class`.  This allows you to take an *instance* of `f` and manipulate it as you see fit.

```
class F:
    def __init__(self,y=10):
        self.y = y

f1 = F()

f2 = F(y=11)

f1.y, f2.y
Out[17]: (10, 11)
```

-Lastly, globals.  Don't use globals.

Answer (score 1):

In `f()`, instead of referring to `y`, refer to `f.y`.

Comment: @user1988876 Also change `print y` to `print f.y`.

Comment: It does not change the function attribute, as you can see in my edit now

Comment: @user1988876 Your function sets `f.y = 10` immediately before printing. There is no contradiction here.

Comment: @user1988876 Try doing this: `def f(): print f.z; f.z = 5; f()`.  This should explain what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `y` as a global variable and call it inside the function as `global y`.

Comment: Don't use globals if it's unnecessary.

Comment: I know but it all depends on what you are writing. If it is a simple program, this solution gives the result needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, everything is an `object`. Even the function `f` which you define is an `object`.

When you say `f.y = 11`, you are assigning an attribute called `y` to the object `f`. However, this is entirely different from the local variable `y = 10` which you have defined inside of the function.

To inspect an object, you can use the `dir` function: `dir(f)`.

Comment: yes, that correct, how would you change it outside function, if at all it is possible

Comment: If it should be changed from the outside, it should probably be an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

y is a local variable in the function by calling f.y = 11 you create a new variable in the function object (press `dir(f)` to see this) it doesn't change local variable y value.

if you want your variable to change you can either use this

```
def f(val):
  y = val
  print y
```

or make y a global variable

```
y = 10

def f():
  print y
```